# Outlook like calendar control in JavaFX 2.0+

Tags: java, calendar, javafx-2

Is there any outlook like calendar control implemented in javaFX 2.0+?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't meet yet a calendar control implemented in pure javaFX 2.0. However you can choose alternative ways:
1. Swing calendar component integrated into JavaFX. See for example [Migcalendar](http://migcalendar.com). It is commercial though.
2. JS/JQuery calendar control in HTML file loaded by webEngine and viewed by webView. See for example [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).

Comment: Finally I chose this answer as the correct one. 

I myself used this approach in my program, but it still persists some limitation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

- http://javafxwidgets.blogspot.com/2012/01/simple-calendar-for-javafx-20.html
- http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/creating-datepicker-control

Comment: Actually, they are date picker control, while I need a MS Outlook like calendar control.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Uluk's second suggestion, unless you want to build a pure JavaFX version yourself, I'd suggest wrapping something like [Google Calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar) in a [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) and programming it via a Java/JavaScript bridge.

Comment: I integrate jQuery plugin as in this link http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-event-calendar/ into my javafx 2.0 application successfully, but I use it through a JSON call from jQuery to JSON JAX-WS web service, which is rather weird.

I tried to use Java/JS bridge as this link: https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx, but not sure is it possible to transfer complex array object through this bridge or not.

Do you have experience about that?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by now you are on JavaFX 8. Then you could try [CalendarFX](http://calendarfx.com).