# JavaFX 2.0 Schedule Table Component

Tags: tableview, javafx-2

I'm working on a school project now, do you have any idea on how can I achieve this kind of table in JavaFX 2?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Appointment Table]

Comment: Maybe this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546315/outlook-like-calendar-control-in-javafx-2-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Agenda control from JFXtras

http://jfxtras.org/