# JavaFX outlook like calendar

Tags: java, jquery, calendar, outlook, jfxtras

Now I know that this question has been asked already, but the solution there didn't help me much

As the title suggests, I am looking for a way to implement an Outlook like calendar into my JavaFX application.

I already tried out fullcalendar, but I didn't manage to start the jQueries, which are needed. I tried a lot of methods, but they either aren't working or I'm too dumb to implement it correctly

I also tried jfxtras agenda, I really like the controls and the look of it, unfortunately I'm a rather inexperienced programmer and therefore I'm not really capable of saving these entries

So, if someone could show me an easy - to - implement calendar or a guide to either fullcalendar or jfxtras agenda, I would be very grateful
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
Here are the links,
1) Fullcalendar [How to add JQuery onto JavaFx WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947543/how-to-add-jquery-onto-javafx-webview)

2) Similar question: [Outlook like calendar control in JavaFX 2.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546315/outlook-like-calendar-control-in-javafx-2-0)

Comment: Please explain, I never used Outlook, what does an "Outlook like calender" mean? And would you mind to link where "this question has been asked already"?

Comment: With an outlook like calendar, I mean a calendar, where you can select a specific day and see the whole day in hours (like 1am - 2am etc) or select a month / year and see the days / months. Also, a very important fact is that you can add notes / tasks to a day and a time, I will searc for the links and include them

Comment: @MouseEvent I now included the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, JFXtras has a samples in which you can add appointments to Agenda. You can download it from the jfxtras.org website and play with it.

The source code ain't that complex (all you need to do is implement an add appointment callback, see line 44.), but you will need to code yourself. Agenda only does the displaying of the appointments, it is your responsibility to store and retrieve them from your domain model.
https://github.com/JFXtras/jfxtras-labs-samples/blob/8.0/src/main/java/jfxtras/samples/controls/agenda/AgendaSample1.java

Basically what you need to do is:

- implement the localDateTimeRangeCallback and set the appointment collection in that method with data from your domain
- implement newAppointmentCallback and store new appointments in your domain
- monitor the appointments collection for removals, and remove the corresponding appointments in your domain.

Comment: Your solutions sounds pretty simple and I will try to implement it! Thank you very much, you helped me a lot.